# How can I test android IAP purchases with real products?

Tags: java, android

I am coding a simple app that allows in app purchases. I already tested using the SKU code android.test.purchased and everything works.

I went into my google play console, created an app, uploaded a APK to alpha manager and created a IAP product.

Next I replaced the android.test.purchased SKU with the real one and added my base64 public key.

I released the alpha build and activated the IAP, but every time I install the signed APK I get an error with IAPs now that goes like this: Not authenticated. Please sign into google play and try again.

Yes, I am already signed into google play. I'm not sure what the problem here is. How can I test IAPs with my apps real products?

Comment: If your developer account is the same as the account on the device you cannot purchase any of your IAPs

Comment: I am logged into the same google developer account as the account which has the google console. Is it possible you need to configure it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check for below points.

1. Make sure your Google account has been added as test account on
   developer account. Login to market.android.com/publish.
2. Click settings, "Account details".
3. Add e-mail adresses to the field "License testing"
4. To test purchase in a new version of an existing app upload the new
   version to Google Play as a draft before you start the test
5. Test all in app purchase, test single issues before subscription
   In addition please refer link, https://developer.android.com/training/in-app-billing/test-iab-app.html and https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_testing.html